# Adjusting the sparklines chart type

Tags: javascript, shieldui, sparklines

I went through the docs available but sill can’t figure out quite much how the ShieldUI sparklines JavaScript chart is used.  I don’t see such a type e.g.

```
dataSeries: [{
    seriesType: "sparklines",
```

but I see “area” instead. I tried with bar, line- it also works but why isn’t there an explicit type for that?
And one more thing- could I use all types as sparklines chart type?

Answer (score 0):

The sparklines is a lightweight version or a layout in which data is being visualized using a Shield UI JavaScript chart. This isn’t a chart type, but a way a chart is being showed. 
The purpose is to provide users the most important information at a glance. Therefore all unnecessary features are turned off. Like for example these ones:

```
        seriesSettings: {
            line: {
                activeSettings: {
                    pointHoveredState: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
                pointMark: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
```

It is being assumed that the user won’t interact with the chart- hover points, hide or show data series by clicking on the legend and so on.
Answering your second question- although all chart types can me formatted to fit the sparklines layout, pie for example won’t be a good idea. Not only for the reasons mention already, but also because a readable pie chart shouldn’t normally be the size that a sparklines chart layout usually has.

In addition a good way to use the sparklines chart layout is to show only one data series, keeping things simple. Shal there be a need for more detailed information- that you should switch to a normal chart layout of the desired type. .